# When I save pdf using jsPDF, can I save only 3 sheets from the beginning?

Tags: jspdf

First of all, I am not good at English. I am sorry

When I save the pdf file as an attachment using jspdf, can I save only 3 sheets from the beginning?
I can't find an example of saving only a specific page, so I'm asking you a question

My guess is that when you press the registration button, you can save it as 3 sheets only if the extension of the attachment is pdf

My guess ->

1. Register after user adds attachment form submit
2. If the storage extension is pdf in the saved api,
   2-1. Read jsPDF and bring only the first 3 pages to make a new pdf
   2-2. Save only 3 pages

```
    function fnInsert(){
    if($("#title").val() === ''){
        alert("Please enter a title.");
        return false;
    }
    
    var ext = $('[name=upload_0]').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

    if($.inArray(ext, ['pdf']) == -1) {
    /* When pdf, read jsPDf and bring only the first 3 pages to create a new pdf */
        

       }
            

    /* Save to 3-page pdf DB */


    $("#aform").attr({action:"/cms/data/insertDataMgt.do", method:'post'}).submit();
    }
```

I don't know what to do with the annotated part

Comment: Hi, K J. Thank you for your comment.
doc.addpage(); doc.addpage(); doc.addpage(); doc.save("sample.pdf"): do you mean this?
I'm sorry if I misunderstood
If you can show me an example, thank you

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment, K J
I will refer to it and use it as you told me. thanks